# Using PHP DBC Class in other files

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, pdo

Coming from Java I am very confused how the PHP class system works. I have a DBC class and a User class. Both I have to use in a third PHP file (signup.inc.php), but this error occurs: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DBC::prepare() in User.php DBC::prepare().

So User.php doesn't know that $this->dbc is a PDO object? I tried to google something similar but still don't get how the class/inheritance system works. Does anyone have a tip or tips for improvement?

DBC.php (db connection with singleton):

```
class DBC {

private $connection;
public static $_instance;
private $dbServer = "...";
private $dbUsername = "...";
private $dbPassword = "...";
private $dbName = "...";

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!self::$_instance) {
        self::$_instance = new self();

        return self::$_instance;

    } else {
        return self::$_instance;

    }
}

private function __construct() {

    try {

        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbServer.";dbname=".$this->dbName,
        $this->dbUsername,
        $this->dbPassword,
        [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        ]);

        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        self::$_instance = $this->connection;
```

doesn't show the rest of this file in one piece ...

```
} catch (PDOException $error) {
            #...
        }

    }

    private function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }

}
```

User.php:

```
include_once 'DBC.php';

    class User {

        protected $email;
        protected $...;
        protected $...;
        protected $...;
        protected $...;
        protected $...;

        public function __construct($dbc) {
            $this->dbc = DBC::getInstance();
        }

    function findByEmail ($email) {

            $statement = $this->dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email = :user_email");
            $statement->bindParam(":user_email", $email);
            $statement->execute();

            if ($statement->rowCount() > 0) {

                return false;

            } else {

                return $this->createUserFromDB($statement);
            }

        }
```

And the call in signup.inc.php:

```
 require_once 'DBC.php';
    require_once 'User.php';

        $dbc = DBC::getInstance();
        $user = new User($dbc);
```

Comment: the error message is pretty clear: there is no such method in the DBC class, indeed, as and it can be clearly seen from the code you posted, there is no such method. So why you are trying to call it? Either way, the DBC class is redundant and I would recommend to get rid of it

Comment: No but dbc is (should be somehow) a PDO object. 
1. Creation in DBC: $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host ...
2. Pass to signleton: self::$_instance = $this->connection;
and then to user... 
Do i need to extend the DBC class with PDO so it work like I inteded it?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice the duplicate marker on my phone! Thanks very much, I'll replace it
Funfact: This code posted here was a try to make it more common for better use. Prior to this I already had the solution you provided but didn't think of it passing the dbc in other constructors. Mixed it up with java and thought I need an extra class for it